# Can't figure out how to fix this script in perl

Tags: perl, skype, argv

I'm running this script in perl and correctly putting in the id and port. however, I keep getting "scalar found where operator expected at line 16 near"'skype://1024,'$ARGV"

```
    #!usr/perl/bin
    use LWP::UserAgent;
    system("color a");
    system("title Skype <<");
    system("cls");
    if(!$ARGV[0]||!$ARGV[1]) {
    print q {

    Usage : perl skype.pl [userid] [port=1024,80,433]
    };
    }
    else {
    use IO::Socket;
    my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET (
    PeerAddr => 'skype://'.$ARGV[0],
    PeerPort => 'skype://1024,'$ARGV[1],
    Proto => 'tcp',
    );
    die "Video Call Error: $!\n" unless $sock;
    print $sock "skype://0x77656263616d5f647269766572\n";
    system("start ".$sock);
    }
    # jvoid(document.write(document.currentUser.id));
```

Answer (score 6):

You have a typo there:

```
PeerPort => 'skype://1024,'$ARGV[1],
```

Should be:

```
PeerPort => 'skype://1024,'.$ARGV[1],
           #               ^--- missing period
```